# How to import large database into local database

Tags: mysql, import, export, mariadb, dump

I'm going to import the database from serve to my local.

Dumped file's size is 5GB.

How can I export and import database quickly?

Comment: I would suggest using the command line `mysql.exe` processor. PHP or rather `phpMyAdmin` will probably timeout using standard (sensible) config parameters

Answer (score 0):

Oxymoron:  "quickly" versus "shoveling 5GB around".

If not already dumped:

```
mysqldump --opt ... | mysql ...
```

Depending on where you execute that pipe, one or the other would have `-h` to refer to the other machine.

If already dumped via `mysqldump` to, say, `db.dump`, then

```
mysql ... < db.dump
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple dump using mysqldump will create a text file with instructions to recreate the database. This process is slow, lock tables and usually results in a large file.

If you need to backup and restore large databases I recommend to take a look at [Percona XtraBackup](https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-xtrabackup).

XtraBackup works by copying the database files directly from the MySql folder, which results in data that is internally inconsistent, but then it performs crash recovery on the files to make them a consistent, usable database again.